# Hubspot bulk import API limit issue

Tags: hubspot, hubspot-crm, hubspot-cms, hubspot-api

I made a POST request to this Hubspot endpoint `https://api.hubapi.com/crm/v3/imports/` and got the following response with status code 429

`{"status":"error","message":"This portal has surpassed the daily number of imports it can run - 500","errorType":"PAID_PORTAL_IMPORTS_LIMIT","errorTokens":{"totalImportsLimit":["500"],"totalImports":["501"]},"correlationId":"123fakeid"}`

What is confusing is that I made a GET request to this Hubspot endpoint `https://api.hubapi.com/integrations/v1/limit/daily`, and it showed us as having 499000 imports for the day remaining.

Any assistance would please be appreciated.

PS: We have Professional tier Hubspot subscription.

Answer (score 0):

The limit is not limited to the imports API, all HubSpot authenticated API calls count against it. Additionally the daily limit endpoint also counts against the daily limit.

If you think you're seeing that 429 response in error, contact HubSpot support. [help.hubspot.com](https://help.hubspot.com)